# Getting Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back in magento 2.3.2 EE while the order is placing

Tags: magento2

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back in /var/www/html/vype/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3981 in /var/www/html/vype/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61

Comment: Same here on magento CE 2.3 while creating a shipment in the backend i get this error in the server error log.

Comment: Hi Friends, Any suggestions?

Comment: Check your magento error log, there should be the real error. This is a message that db changes where reverted

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to figure out the cause:

1. check your log file to see the real error
2. change your magento to developer mode and enable debugging.
   Add this to your **index.php** and **pub/index.php**

   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
   error_reporting(E_ALL);

Then try to reproduce the error again and you should see more information now.

For example I got this message:

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
> Amasty\AdminActionsLog\Observer\HandleModelSaveBefore::prepareProductOptionsDataAsArray()
> must be of the type array, null given

So for me the third party extension Amasty\AdminActionsLog caused the bug.